# How to Continue a Line Feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, editing, line, digitizing

I'm looking for a way to continue a line feature in QGIS. I have checked  the Digitizing Tools plugin (both regular and advanced) for a Prolong Line tool, but I haven't had luck. In ArcGIS there's a Continue Feature button when editing but I haven't found one so far in QGIS. I'm looking for a way to do this while editing/digitizing rather than through code. Can this be done?

Comment: Use the Node Tool http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41663/editing-polylines-in-qgis-extend-trim-fillet-etc

Comment: QGIS 2.16 Extend Line Tool http://changelog.qgis.org/media/images/entries/52726f3b8cd8b62d63a32b9628dd8d3cef53172c.gif

Comment: Good to know that Extend Line comes out in the next version, I'm looking forward to working with 2.16.

Comment: QGIS 2.16 is available here http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Digitizing Tools plugin has to amend line function

https://github.com/bstroebl/DigitizingTools/wiki/Usage

Prolong line

applies to: line layer (multi or single part)

Continue editing existing online features. Just click any end point of an existing line and digitize new vertices as if you would digitize the new feature.

[image]

Comment: This appears to do what I want it to based on the description, however I'm searching for what the icon looks like. I do have Digitizing Tools enabled, but I'm having trouble finding the tool. I'm using 2.14.0-Essen, if that's helpful.

Comment: @RachelW I am looking for the same!

Comment: Cant find this...

Answer (score 5):

In the next release (8 july 2016) this wil be fixed.  Have a look at http://changelog.linfiniti.com/en/qgis/version/2.16.0/

There you can read:

> Feature: Extend linestring geometries with reshape tool
>
> The reshape tool now allows you to extend linestrings, by starting a
>   reshape at either a line's start or end point.
>
> This feature was developed by Martin Dobias

Untill then you can do what Mapperz suggests

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS 3.4 (and probably before that), you can use the ‘Vertex’ tool (which is next to ‘Add line’ on the toolbar, by default). Choose it, then hover the mouse over the ending or starting point of a line, and you'll see a plus symbol next to it—this allows you to continue the line. Similarly, it allows you to add a new point between other two by hovering the cursor there and clicking on the plus symbol that appears.

Comment: This is already answered elsewhere but now I landed here from a repeat web search—so I guess I'll leave the proper answer for when I forget it again.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS3.x, you can use advanced digital tools. You could set 'parallel' mode, then click the line you want extend.there will appear a dashed line along the former line like what in AutoCAD.

Of course, it's still slow and stupid. But the method doesn't depend on any third party plugins.

Comment: Getting this to work in 3.12 is tricky for me. I can only get it to work if I click 'Reshape' -> click on the line endpoint -> toggle/click Parallel on the Advanced Digitizing tools -> then click back on the line endpoint again. But it works.